# Flutter IoS App crash when submitted to appStore

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, symbolicatecrash

I'm a Flutter developer and I'm trying to deploy my first IOS app developed with Flutter (I don't know anything about the Apple world). I submitted an app on the appstore via codeMagic, but I couldn't test it before because I dont have iPhone and mac.

Apple sent me 2 crashlogs telling me that they tried to launch the app, but it crashed. I understood that I had to symbolic logs to get more info, but I'm reaching the limits of what I can do with the CodeMagic VM (20mn sessions, and I don't know anything about macOS...) I tried symbolizing with macSymbolicator on this VM but it doesn't work, it says it doesn't understand crashlogs (unknown format)

Could someone do it for me please and tell me what crashes??

The crashlogs provided by Apple:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZdSxcr-roAUe3Tm7SLqny8uKef4cMni4/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTKdI7OPbKtpFO4hydepFduzS_YPzD_O/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance !

Sebastien, Nantes, France

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide more detail,  but honestly having access to an iOS device and macOS is really a requirement to release an app on iOS. If you don't have them/can't get them then just stick with the Android release. You will find it too hard to debug and produce a reliable product without

Comment: Thanks Paulw11, I developed it by Flutter because I dont want to develop it like a native app and I dont have mac and Iphone.I added the crashlogs in the post. Could you help me to analyse it please ?

Comment: I understand why you chose flutter, but unfortunately while Flutter lets you develop cross platform code, you are going to need access to both platforms to test and debug and to provide a good experience for users on both platforms. Those crash logs don't mean anything. You need to run your app on an iOS device under the debugger

Comment: OK thanks, Apple says that i can symbolicate, it will provide no interisting information ? i'm looking someone with an iphone... Can we install the IPA file directly on an iphone ?

Comment: You will want to connect the iPhone to a mac running Xcode and load the  Xcode project that Flutter produces and run that so that you can see what is happening.  Symbolicating a flutter crash probably won't help you much but you can try.  Are you using null safety in your flutter project?  A common cause of crashes is accessing something that is null

Comment: ok thanks I understand, yes i use null safety... But on Android non problem with this app ! If i send you all the access and artefacts, coul you do something for me ? I cant buy an macOS for that !

Comment: I know this may sound mean, but if you can't pay the price for iOS development, just stick to Android.  The company I work develops in Flutter and we give all of our mobile developers a Mac and both Android and iOS devices

Comment: OK I see, it's for a non benefit organization, not a company. We dont have the money for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like Odevio (https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI) to do test your app from Windows or Linux. Odevio is a tool that lets you access MacOs remote machines.

To install Odevio visit https://www.odevio.com, then setup your developer account with Odevio (https://odevio-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/6_configure_app_store_connect.html) once this is done you can start building your app in the build menu.